# PHPunit test for a html post code

Tags: php

The code below is my code to check what data is present in the checkbox array and then inserting that code into my database. I have never done any testing or phpunit testing as a matter of fact. I am confused on where to even begin to try to write a test for this piece of code. I have researched a lot on phpunit and still am not grasping the concept of how to write the test for this. Maybe it is just me not understanding how to do it. I would greatly appreciate some help and feedback on how to go about this!

```
if(!empty($_POST['checkbox']))
  {
    foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $check) 
    {
           echo "</br>";
           echo ($check);
           $sql= "INSERT INTO UserPicks (userID, game) VALUES ('$_POST[userID]','$_POST[game]')";
    }
```

Comment: Aside from the SQL injection risks in this code: phpunit can't simply be used to test any code that you have written, it requires you to write you code in a particular way that facilitates writing unit tests that allow component methods to be tested in isolation... an example in this case would be eliminating the dependency on $_POST

Comment: Nor are you actually doing anything with the $sql string that you're creating, other than overwriting it each iteration of the loop if you have multiple checkboxes checked

Comment: How would you define a correct response? Would it be a string you are looking for? Is there a specific reason to use PHPUnit, or should you try some of your own automated testing concepts first, then move to PHPUnit. Its easier to understand the benefits of PHPUnit once you start trying to "roll your own"

Comment: @MarkBaker it looks like you do a lot of phpunit testing https://travis-ci.org/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/jobs/21796638 do you agree with me in that you should try building simple `assert $foo == $bar` style tests before jumping into phpunit to understand what the benefits of the suite are? Also 100% agree that writing testable code.

Comment: @MarkBaker Something I learned in class that to get good code coverage you try to test every line of code. Although we did it in Java I wasn't sure how it should be done. So are you saying that only code where there can be an issue should be tested? Just like you said my array is just being printed from the loop and really does not need to be tested.

Comment: @Victory I am not sure like I told Mark that when I tested with doing JUnit to get better code coverage we tried to test as many lines as possible. So I figured we would test every line in php as well.

Comment: `are you saying that only code where there can be an issue should be tested?` Not at all, your code should be tested; but PHPUnit isn't the appropriate tool to test code unless that code has been written in a way that facilitates unit testing....

Comment: @MarkBaker oh that makes complete sense now! So do you recommend any other tools to test my code that I should research into?

Comment: Typically you should write your code as small, individually testable methods that accept a set of inputs as arguments, and that return an output (rather than echoing output), and where any additional dependencies (such as database access) can be simulated

Comment: But tools like PHPSpec or Behat or Codeception might be more appropriate for testing of an application rather than its individual units, and are less concerned about how your code is written